# Query Azure Table Storage with Rest Api

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to retrieve data from azure data table using the rest api.The Url looks something like this.

```
https://<service-url>/Customers(PartitionKey='MyPartition')
```

The Api error's out with **Invalid data**.

If I add RowKey as well along with PartitionKey something like this. It works.

```
https://<service-url>/Customers(PartitionKey='MyPartition',RowKey='MyRowKey1')
```

Is it necessary to pass the RowKey?

What If I just want to retrieve all data from one partition.
I know, we can add a $filter in the query parameter but wouldn't it cause performance issue?

Please share your ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify both the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` when using this format `https://<service-url>/Customers(xxx)`.

When using `$filter` in the query, as per my test(about 100 records), there's no more difference in time consuming. And I also try to use `SDK` to query just by specifying `PartitionKey`, and I can see it automatically use `$filter` in the backend(by using the tool [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)).